# Controller reseiving object with null fields

Tags: kotlin

Learn Kotlin.

I have DTO.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
open class AbstractDto : Serializable {

    open var id: Long? = null
    open var created: LocalDateTime? = null
    open var updated: LocalDateTime? = null
}

open class UserDto : AbstractDto() {

    open var height: Int? = null
    open var weight: Double? = null
    open var gender: String? = null
    open var birthDate: LocalDateTime? = null
    open val contacts: List<ContactDto> = ArrayList()
}
```

I have controller, which inherits of abstract class, which inherits of interface:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@ControllerImpl
class UserController : AbstractController<User, UserDto, UserMapper, UserRepository, UserServiceImpl>()

open class AbstractController<
        E : AbstractEntity,
        D : AbstractDto,
        M : AbstractMapper<E, D>,
        R : CommonRepository<E>,
        S : AbstractService<E, D, M, R>
        > : CommonController<D> {

    private val service: S? = null

    override fun save(dto: D?): ResponseEntity<D> = ResponseEntity.ok(service!!.save(dto)!!)

    override fun update(dto: D): ResponseEntity<D> = ResponseEntity.ok(service!!.update(dto)!!)

    override fun get(id: Long): ResponseEntity<D> = ResponseEntity.ok(service!!.get(id)!!)

    override fun getAll(pageable: Pageable): ResponseEntity<Page<D>> = ResponseEntity.ok(service!!.getAll(pageable))

    override fun delete(id: Long): ResponseEntity<Boolean> = ResponseEntity.ok(service!!.delete(id))
}

interface CommonController<D : AbstractDto> {

    @PostMapping
    fun save(dto: D?): ResponseEntity<D>

    @PutMapping
    fun update(dto: D): ResponseEntity<D>

    @GetMapping("/all")
    fun get(id: Long): ResponseEntity<D>

    @GetMapping
    fun getAll(pageable: Pageable): ResponseEntity<Page<D>>

    @DeleteMapping
    fun delete(id: Long): ResponseEntity<Boolean>
}
```

Sending POST-request:

```
{
    "height": 180,
    "weight": 75,
    "user": 1
}
```

My controller reseive DTO, in which all fields are null. Advice, what wrong? It worked in simple controller, before moving to abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a small Kotlin course because it seems you haven't understood much about writing OO in Kotlin.

You can do something like this :

```
open class AbstractDto(open var id: Long? = null,
                       open var created: LocalDateTime? = null,
                       open var updated: LocalDateTime? = null)


open class UserDto(override var id: Long? = null,
                   override var created: LocalDateTime? = null,
                   override var updated: LocalDateTime? = null,
                   var height: Int? = null
                   var weight: Double? = null
                   var gender: String? = null
                   var birthDate: LocalDateTime? = null
                   val contacts: List<String> = ArrayList()) : AbstractDto(id,
        created,
        updated
)
```

You initialize your fields to null without using a constructor so they can never be changed. If you add a constructor you should be able to init your fields.

Comment: I did what you said, but nothing changes. Fields are null. Than, you say that fields, initialized without constructor, can't be changed. But they all are var, not final. How to understand your statement?

Comment: Ok the problem I solved was only the init through Kotlin. You have to share your conf Jackson. Are you using spring boot?

Comment: Yes, I using Spring Boot. Jackson configs are default.

Comment: Try to change your classes with data class see https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-kotlin

Comment: are you sure that problem for case where fields not works in inheritor from abstract class is in Jackson?

Comment: @Вячеслав Чернышов may be. He should check if some fields are initialized. But it seems ti was not the case at first.